# how to find subitems of a row in cell array matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell, subitem

I have cell array that is as follow:

```
S{1} = [10,20,30,40,50];
S{2} = [10,20,40,50];
S{3} = [10,50,510];
S{4} = [10,20,70,40,60];
S{5} = [20,40];
```

and, i need to find rows of cell that are subitem of:

```
[10,20,30,40,50,60]
```

for above example result is :

```
1,2,5
```

because row 1 and row 2 and and row 5 only have subitems of [10,20,30,40,50,60] .

in my work cell array is big. and i need a fast code.

Comment: The way you have written it S is not a cell. Did you mean `S{1}=..`, etc

Comment: yes. cell define is edited

Answer (score 7):

Let

```
S{1} = [10,20,30,40,50];
S{2} = [10,20,40,50];
S{3} = [10,50,510];
S{4} = [10,20,70,40,60];
S{5} = [20,40];            % data
t = [10,20,30,40,50,60];   % target values
```

Then, you can apply [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) and [`all`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to each cell's contents via [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). The result is a logical vector, from which you obtain the desired indices with [`find`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
result = find(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(x, t)), S));
```

An alternative (I don't know which one will be faster in your case) is to replace `ismember` by computing all pairwise comparisons with [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and then applying [`any`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html):

```
result = find(cellfun(@(x) all(any(bsxfun(@eq, t(:), x(:).'), 1)), S));
```