# how to find row from numeric cell that contain target vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell, numeric

I have cell array that is as follow:

```
S{1} = [10,20,30,40,50];
S{2} = [10,20,40,50];
S{3} = [10,50,510];
S{4} = [10,20,70,40,60];
S{5} = [20,40];
```

and,i have a target vector:

```
T=[10,70]
```

i need to find rows of cell that T is subitem of those.
for above example result is : 4

because T is  subitems of row 4.

Comment: Just swap `x` and `t` in my answer to [your previous, very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44408921/2586922)

Answer (score 3):

Get the count of matches for each cell against `T` and see which cells have a match count being equal to the number of elements in `T`, indicating that those cells have all elements from `T`. The assumption here is that we have unique elements in each of those cells.

Here's the implementation -

```
find(cellfun(@(x) nnz(ismember(x, T)), S) == numel(T))
```

Or as suggested by `@Leander Moesinger` we can get the matches for each element off `T` across all elements in each cell and then simply use `all()`, like so -

```
find(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(T,x)),S))
```

Comment: wouldn't `find(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(T,x)),S))` do the same thing a bit faster?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Lovely! Should be faster. Thanks! Updated.